# Confirm data sent through socket had been received in the server

Tags: android, java-websocket, android-websocket

I defined the websocket in my android app as below:

```
package com.oryx.geoop

import android.content.Context
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake
import java.lang.Exception
import java.net.URI

lateinit var mWebSocketClient: WebSocketClient


class SocketClient {
    val uri = URI("ws://10.0.2.2:8080/ws")


    val message = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun connectWebSocket(context: Context) {
        // Setup stuff

        mWebSocketClient = object : WebSocketClient(uri) {
            override fun onError(ex: Exception?) {
                // TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onClose(code: Int, reason: String?, remote: Boolean) {
                // TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onOpen(serverHandshake: ServerHandshake) {
                // Opened do some stuff
            }

            override fun onMessage(s: String) {
                message.postValue(s)
            }
        }
        mWebSocketClient.connect()
    }
}
```

And I use it to send data to the server as below, after checking the socket is opened or not:

```
if (mWebSocketClient.isOpen) {
      mWebSocketClient.send(jObj.toString())
} else {
      client.connectWebSocket(p0)
      mWebSocketClient.send(data)
}
```

But still have doubt as connection may be cut somewhere in between, so need the server to send back a confirmation note to the android app.

How can I make the app understand the returned msg from the server as a confirmation of receiving the data the mobile itself sent.
Let's say the msg sent back from the server is `"confirmed, $data"`

Comment: You can send a message back to the device from the server on every message. In which language the server has setup ?

Comment: @theapache64 the server is setup in `Rust`, and it send a confirmation msg as `self.out.broadcast(msg);` but how can I make the android app understand this msg is a confirmation one, not a normal one.

Comment: I've added an answer, please check if it works with your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On every message you send to the server, the server can send back a confirmation message easily. The method name depends on the server stack you use. Mostly, it's something like `client.sendMessage(yourMessage)`

Now, let's answer your question which you asked in the comments section.

> How can I make the android app understand this msg is a confirmation
>   one, not a normal one ?

Rather than passing raw text, you can do the communication in `JSON`

For example,

You can send normal response in below format

```
{
  "type": "NORMAL",
  "id": "someUniqueIdOfTheMessage",
  "message": "This is some normal message"
}
```

and for the confirmation,the server can send back something like this

```
{
  "type": "CONFIRMATION",
  "id": "someUniqueIdOfTheMessage"
}
```